# Pass the location of a file to a method in java?

Tags: java, swing, file, methods

I'm trying to create an object that gets a file location and sets an `jEditorPane` to the contents of the located file.

Code:

```
File file = new File("Summary.html");
private void EditoPaneMethod(File file) {
    frmRules.pack();
    frmRules.setVisible(true);
    edpRules.setEditable(false);
    try {
        edpRules.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Edit:
okay maybe my question is unclear, here's my code:

```
    frmRules.pack();
    frmRules.setVisible(true);
    edpRules.setEditable(false);
    File file = new File("Summary.html");
    try {
        edpRules.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Now since there are many different files I would like to Display and it would be inefficient to have the same code for each file I've decided to create a method See method  EditoPaneMethod() so that every time I coded a button with the method the button displays the file relevant to the button.

Comment: What's wrong with what you are doing?

Comment: Right direction of what?  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: In the button where the code is my ide says Required file Found no arguments

Comment: You need to call the method with a `File` instance as an argument.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you declare the file such as:

```
File myFile = new File("Summary.html");
```

you should supply this to the method, like this:

```
EditoPaneMethod(myFile)
```

The reason I have included this is since it seems to me by your comments that you think you could be passing the variable file to the method just because the parameter happens to have the same name as the variable you declared.

Comment: thx your explanation did help after 3 days of trying to figure it out I will modify your answer, (when I get time) to explain what I did done wrong

Comment: If you need any help, don't hesitate to ask :)